# Encountering issue while calling the functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm facing an error in my python program I know what is the error but don't know how to fix, error is when `update_employee` is called as it is calling the `search_employee` and executing the next line that is `if condition` but the value that is being checked inside if condition is not updated yet as it will be updated when I click the search button from `search_employee`.

I want to fix this that `if condition` would have to run after the button is pressed and values of self.UPDATE are updated in `search_from_database`, Here is the code:

```
import mysql.connector
from tkinter import *

class AdminPanel:
    def __init__(self, main):
        self.main = main
        self.frame = None
        self.UPDATE = {'ID': '', 'Found': False}
        self.connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host="localhost",
            user="root",
            password="",
            database="employee-management"
        )
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def update_employee(self):
        self.search_employee()
        if self.UPDATE['Found']:
            # self.add_employee()

    def search_employee(self):
        if self.frame is not None:
            self.frame.destroy()
        self.frame = Frame(self.main, pady=10, padx=10, relief=RAISED)
        first_name = Entry(self.frame, font='lucid 15', width=15)
        first_name.grid(row=0, column=1)
        last_name = Entry(self.frame, font='lucid 15', width=15)
        last_name.grid(row=1, column=1)
        Button(self.frame, text='Search', font='arial 10 bold', pady=3, padx=5,
               command=lambda: self.search_from_database(first_name.get(), last_name.get()))\
            .grid(row=3, column=1, pady=10)
        self.frame.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)

    def search_from_database(self, f_name, l_name):
        query = "SELECT id,fname,lname FROM empdata"
        self.cursor.execute(query)
        values = self.cursor.fetchall()
        for data in values:
            if data[1] == f_name and data[2] == l_name:
                self.UPDATE.update({'ID': data[0], 'Found': True})
                break


root = Tk()
obj = AdminPanel(root)
obj.update_employee()
root.mainloop()
```

I need to use the search function on other places so I can't change the function call inside the `search_from_database` every time if I call `update_employee` from `search_from_database`, I want to make search function a general function that every time I need to search any employee to update or delete I can use this.

Comment: It's unclear. By "if condition", you mean the if statement ```if self.frame is not None``` or the statement ```if self.UPDATE['Found']```? For the latter, did you check the ```self.UPDATE.update({'ID': data[0], 'Found': True})``` is called?

Comment: @relent95 yes I checked, every thing is okay, the issue is in `update_employee()` that it is calling the `search_employee()` function and then the next `if self.UPDATE['Found']`, so the value is not updated in dictionary for `ID` and `Found` as `search_from_database()` will not run until we press the button, I want to run search_employee then search from database as button is clicked, and after that I need to run `if self.UPDATE['Found']`

Comment: You need to edit the question, instead of adding a comment. In short, you want to the line ```if self.UPDATE['Found']:``` is executed after the "Search" button is clicked. Right? Then, you should do the work in the event handler ```search_from_database()```, not in the ```update_employee()```.

Comment: @relent95 yup, I got the problem, Thank you